# Formatting String by padding with leading zeros in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

We have one old comments column with these comments ACCTFEETOMANAGER, ACCTFEEFRMMANAGER, ACCTFNWRKSRMANAGER in SQL table.

Now I have to convert this to 'ACCTFEE TO MANAGER', but the total character should be 24.

The expected result will be "000000ACCTFEE TO MANAGER", '00000ACCTFEE FRM MANAGER', '00ACCTF N WRK SR MANAGER'

If anyone has an idea please reply.

Comment: Yes, here is an idea: Stop storing multiple things in one column. Is this multiple rows, or a single row with comma separators? Proper sample data and expected results (as `CREATE TABLE/INSERT`) would help

Comment: You state you have those exact 3 comments which you want to replace, so why not just use `replace`?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you provide some example data and expected results, because as it is it looks like you simply need to swap out one value for another value for three specific values.

Two possible ways, of many, would be

```
select t.comments, 
    Replace(
        Replace(
            Replace(comments,'ACCTFEETOMANAGER','000000ACCTFEE TO MANAGER'
            ),'ACCTFEEFRMMANAGER','00000ACCTFEE FRM MANAGER'
        ),'ACCTFNWRKSRMANAGER','00ACCTF N WRK SR MANAGER'
    ) Result
from t


with map as (
    select * from (
        values 
            ('ACCTFEETOMANAGER','000000ACCTFEE TO MANAGER'),
            ('ACCTFEEFRMMANAGER','00000ACCTFEE FRM MANAGER'),
            ('ACCTFNWRKSRMANAGER','00ACCTF N WRK SR MANAGER')
    )v(s,t)
)
select t.comments, m.t Result
from t
join map m on m.s=t.comments
```

Comment: Thank you STU, but if the text changes then this will not work. I need code for any text and the column width should be 24.  
If you can add spaces after MANAGER to make 24 characters will be fine as well.

Comment: So any string of variable length can be padded out with zeros to be a fixed length, that's no problem at all - but you are adding spaces, so by what logic does `ACCTFEET` become `ACCTFEE T` etc